# How to block payload when Payload when Payload Buffer does not have 15 values

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm collecting data from Modbus slave devices, but sometimes the Payload Buffer does not have 15 values.

How can I block the payload if it does not have all of the 15 values?

```
if (msg.topic === "sensor1" || msg.topic === "reset") {
var msg1 = { payload : msg.payload[1]};
var msg2 = { payload : msg.payload[3]};
var msg3 = { payload : msg.payload[5]};
var msg4 = { payload : msg.payload[7]};
var msg5 = { payload : msg.payload[9]};
global.set('sensor1Id',msg1.payload);
global.set('sensor1Concentration',msg2.payload);
global.set('sensor1Temperature',msg3.payload);
global.set('sensor1Voltage',msg4.payload);
global.set('sensor1SensorFailure',msg5.payload);
return msg;
}
```

Sometimes I get the following payload:

[1,3,10]

But it should be something like this:

[0,2,0,0,0,31,0,213,0,4,184,47,1,3,10]

Comment: What do you mean by block? Do you mean not send the message further down the flow?

Comment: Also the example of correct you have posted is only 12 bytes long not 15.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I've corrected it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly lets fix the code you've posted

```
if (msg.topic === "sensor1" || msg.topic === "reset") {
  global.set('sensor1Id',msg.payload[1]);
  global.set('sensor1Concentration',msg.payload[3]);
  global.set('sensor1Temperature',msg3.payload[5]);
  global.set('sensor1Voltage',msg4.payload[7]);
  global.set('sensor1SensorFailure',msg5.payload[9]);
  return msg;
}
```

There is no need to create all the extra objects to then set global variables.

If you want to gate that code on the length of the buffer then you can change the `if` statement as follows:

```
if ((msg.topic === "sensor1" || msg.topic === "reset") &&
   msg.payload.length == 12) {
```

This will check that the buffer contains 12 bytes.

Comment: Thank you. But I do not understand one thing you've mentioned.

Can you explain me why you did suggest the following?:

((msg.topic === "sensor1" || msg.topic === "reset") && msg.payload.length == 15)

And not the following?:

(msg.topic === "sensor1" || msg.topic === "reset" && msg.payload.length == 15)

Comment: Because I assumed that you are only interested in messages with the topic of `sensor1` or `reset` and then once we only have those messages we check it's the right length. The extra brackets make sure we do the tests in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a `switch` node before the `function`, and use a test expression like `$length(payload)`, compared to the number 15 -> output to port #1. If you just want to ignore payloads with different lengths, you don't even need to add port #2.